# SELECT TOP inside INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I created this simple database in SQL Server:

```
create database product_test
go

use product_test
go

create table product 
(
    id int identity primary key,
    label varchar(255),
    description text,
    price money, 
);

create table picture 
(
    id int identity primary key, 
    p_path text, 
    product int foreign key references product(id) 
); 

insert into product 
values ('flip phone 100', 'back 2 the future stuff.', 950),
       ('flip phone 200', 's;g material', 1400)

insert into picture 
values ('1.jpg', 1), ('2.jpg', 1), ('3.jpg', 2)
```

What I want is to select **all** products  and **only one** picture for each product. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `inner join (select top 1 etc from lol) img on img.whatever = outer.whatever`?

Comment: which picture do you want?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: what if there is a product without a picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a fan of `outer apply` for this purpose:

```
select p.*, pi.id, pi.path
from product p outer apply
     (select top 1 pi.*
      from picture pi
      where pi.product = p.id
     ) pi;
```

You can include an `order by` to get one particular picture (say, the one with the lowest or highest id).  Or, `order by newid()` to get a random one.

Comment: Hi Gordon, just trying to understand your qry, since I never used APPLY for my devs; in this case, don't you get the same result/exec plan as if using a classic left join?

Comment: @PaulDaubian . . . It should be similar.  However, `APPLY` (or more generally a lateral join) can have better performance, because it does not need to generate all the rows with an additional row number attached.  If you are learning `APPLY`, you can think of it as a correlated subquery in the `FROM` clause, with the advantage that it can return multiple columns and multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
*,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 p2.p_path
    FROM dbo.picture p2
    WHERE p.id = p2.product
) AS picture
FROM dbo.product p
```

Or with join:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM dbo.product p
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT p2.product, MIN(p2.p_path) AS p_path
    FROM dbo.picture p2
    GROUP BY p2.product
) AS pt
ON p.id = pt.product
```

But you need to change p_path to `varchar` type

Comment: This will work but it should be mentioned that if the OP wants to be consistent about which picture will be returned the subquery needs to have an order by.

Comment: the original question says he wants a join.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a correlated sub-query?

```
SELECT *, (SELECT TOP 1 p_path FROM picture WHERE product = p.id ORDER BY id) 
FROM picture p
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

I would use a windowing function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM product 
JOIN (
  SELECT id, product, p_path, 
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY id ASC) as RN
  FROM picture
) pic ON product.id = pic.product AND pic.RN = 1
```

As you can see here I am selecting the picture with the lowest id (`ORDER BY id ASC`) -- you can change this order by to your requirements.

Comment: Interesting you think this will work given you have not supplied a table for the join

Comment: @Paparazzi - lol good catch -- totally left off the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score -1):

just group by and take min or max
left join in case there is no picture

```
select pr.ID, pr.label, pr.text, pr.price
     , min(pic.p_path)
from product pr 
left join picture pic 
on pic.product = pr.ID 
group by pr.ID, pr.label, pr.text, pr.price
```

Comment: It is interesting to me, the OP specifically asks for an inner join (implying that he only wants results with a picture) why would you suggest a left join?

Comment: @Hogan That is covered in my answer. "left join in case there is no picture"

Comment: @Hogan OP also states wants all products.  Based on asking the question in the first place it is not clear OP understands the implications of an inner join.